# SwiftUI: can toolbarBackground modifier take a custom color?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use iOS 16's `toolbarBackground` modifier.  The example gives the following usage:

```
  .toolbarBackground(
      Color.blue,
      for: .tabBar
  )
```

That works as expected.  I have a Color extension that I am using throughout my app that allows it take hex codes:

*Color extension*

```
 extension Color {
  init?(_ hex: String) {
    var str = hex
    if str.hasPrefix("#") {
      str.removeFirst()
    }
    if str.count == 3 {
      str = String(repeating: str[str.startIndex], count: 2)
        + String(repeating: str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)], count: 2)
        + String(repeating: str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)], count: 2)
    } else if !str.count.isMultiple(of: 2) || str.count > 8 {
      return nil
    }
    let scanner = Scanner(string: str)
    var color: UInt64 = 0
    scanner.scanHexInt64(&color)
    if str.count == 2 {
      let gray = Double(Int(color) & 0xFF) / 255
      self.init(.sRGB, red: gray, green: gray, blue: gray, opacity: 1)
    } else if str.count == 4 {
      let gray = Double(Int(color >> 8) & 0x00FF) / 255
      let alpha = Double(Int(color) & 0x00FF) / 255
      self.init(.sRGB, red: gray, green: gray, blue: gray, opacity: alpha)
    } else if str.count == 6 {
      let red = Double(Int(color >> 16) & 0x0000FF) / 255
      let green = Double(Int(color >> 8) & 0x0000FF) / 255
      let blue = Double(Int(color) & 0x0000FF) / 255
      self.init(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: 1)
    } else if str.count == 8 {
      let red = Double(Int(color >> 24) & 0x000000FF) / 255
      let green = Double(Int(color >> 16) & 0x000000FF) / 255
      let blue = Double(Int(color >> 8) & 0x000000FF) / 255
      let alpha = Double(Int(color) & 0x000000FF) / 255
      self.init(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: alpha)
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to use it within the `toolbarBackground` modifier like:

```
 .toolbarBackground(
      Color("##00FF00"),
      for: .tabBar
  )
```

and it's not working.  Is the API still limited to where it can only use basic colors?

Comment: probably a typo, have you tried `Color("#00FF00")`, note only one `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the `toolbarBackground` modifier that is not working,
I suspect that it is your `Color init?(_ hex: String) {...}` function that is not working.

Try this code example and code to convert hex to Color. Works well for me, including for the `toolbarBackground`.

So to answer the question, **no** the API is **not** limited to where it can only use basic colors.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                List(0..<3, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("item-\(i)").foregroundColor(Color(hex: "#0078d4"))
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("bar title")
                .toolbarBackground(Color(hex: "#00FF00"), for: .tabBar)
                .background(Color(hex: "#e2c9ed"))
            }
        }
    }
}


extension Color {

    init(hex: String) {
        let trimHex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let dropHash = String(trimHex.dropFirst()).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let hexString = trimHex.starts(with: "#") ? dropHash : trimHex
        let ui64 = UInt64(hexString, radix: 16)
        let value = ui64 != nil ? Int(ui64!) : 0
        // #RRGGBB
        var components = (
            R: CGFloat((value >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            G: CGFloat((value >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            B: CGFloat((value >> 00) & 0xff) / 255,
            a: CGFloat(1)
        )
        if String(hexString).count == 8 {
            // #RRGGBBAA
            components = (
                R: CGFloat((value >> 24) & 0xff) / 255,
                G: CGFloat((value >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
                B: CGFloat((value >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
                a: CGFloat((value >> 00) & 0xff) / 255
            )
        }
        self.init(.sRGB, red: components.R, green: components.G, blue: components.B, opacity: components.a)
    }

}
```

Comment: that was exactly the issue, thanks a lot!